# Php routing always contains Pages

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

Everytime i try and reference a file or anything, /Pages/ always is at the start of the URL. so i get these errors, and need to change all button links to ../

[image]

My routes.php file is as such

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {


    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('Pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```

I'm using cakephp inside codeanywhere (dont ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $routes->connect('/Pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```